# Can't use C library (function)

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt

The following is my environment:

- Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers(Juno)
- Qt 4.8.3
- Qt Eclipse Integration v1.6.1
- mingw(20120426)

When I create a Qt console project, I just can't use C library functions, such as `exit(int)` or `atoi(string)`.

The error message is such like `Function 'exit' could not be resolved`.

I have included `stdlib.h`, but still can't work.

I don't know if there is some relation with index.

---

**20121109 Update**

Thanks for give me help!

`atoi` is just a example!

Although I write program in c++, but sometimes I want use C library, so I tag it c++.

The following is what I include

- `C:/MinGW/include`
- `C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include`
- `C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++`
- `C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/backward`
- `C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/mingw32`
- `C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include-fixed`

Others are Qt library.

And the following is `main`.

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::exit(0);
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    return a.exec();
}
```

I try this way but still get error message `Function 'exit' could not be resolved`.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you try to #include <cstdlib> and use std::exit(int) instead?

Comment: Related to _what_ index?

Comment: @BoTian its a C program, isnt it?

Comment: I saw the tag C++ so I assumed it's C++.

Comment: Interesting/exotic programming environment, provided the good quality of QTCreator.

Comment: @Baltasarq I use qt under eclipse as well, I'm aware of the good QTCreator quality. its just that I do everything under eclipse

Comment: I have some reason that make me use eclipse, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: What is the setting of "Project->Properties->Settings->Binary Parsers"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, use C++ headers style. For stdlib.h :

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Then, I guess you're not bringing namespace information. Either write :

```
using namespace std;
```

(even if I don't recommend it) or

```
using std::exit    using std::atoi;
```

or use fully qualified names :

```
std::exit(-1);
```

Finally, why do you need such functions like atoi ?

Comment: but even with `<stdlib.h>` it should be able to find the C header

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case which I was able to solve by moving `#include <cstdlib>` to the top of the list of header includes. This means that one of the other header files had a dependency on something in the `cstdlib`. This is not really good practice but they're all system header files and trying to correct them would make the code less portable between similar development systems.

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse C++ Kepler.  This is what I did and it worked for me:
right-click in editor's screen>Run As>Local C/C++ Application.